# Unit test script for $rootScope.$on with function argument

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I tried to check the $rootScope.$on with function argument
but getting error - I have mentioned the error in below

**AngularJS**

```
team = $rootScope.$on('match', function (param) {
   changeTeam(param);
});
```

I tried to write unit test script using Jasmine
**Jasmine**

```
expect($rootScope.$on).toHaveBeenCalledWith('match', Function); // getting error
```

**Error**
Expected spy $on to have been called with [ 'match', Function ] but actual calls were [ 'close', Function ], [ '$destroy', Function ], [ 'close', Function ], [ '$destroy', Function ]

Comment: Try with `jasmine.any(Function)`

Comment: Again getting error like Expected spy $on to have been called with [ 'match', <jasmine.any(function Function() {
            [native code]
        })> ] but actual calls were [ 'close', Function ], [ '$destroy', Function ], [ 'close', Function ], [ '$destroy', Function ]

Comment: I have to check the changeTeam(param); method also, please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Can you post the rest of your Jasmine code? What does your spy initialization look like?

Comment: How are you triggering the 'match' event?

Comment: spy initialization look like `spyOn($rootScope, '$on').andCallThrough();`